# calculate volume of sphere script?

Tags: powershell, math, calculator

I wrote my function to calculate the volume of a sphere but when I execute it ; it shows error ; can someone tell me what's wrong with my script please ?

```
$Diameter3 = Read-Host "Please enter the diameter of the circle "

function VolumnOfSphere  {

    if ($Diameter3 -lt 1) { $Diameter3 = 1 } 

    $Volume = (([math]::Pow(($Diameter3 / 2 ), 3)) * ([math]::PI * 1.1))
    Write-host "The volume of the sphere is $Volume" 
}

VolumeOfSphere
```

Volume (Sphere) = 4/3π x rayon³ that's the normal equation to calculate the volume

Comment: There's a typo in the function signature: `VolumnOfSphere` instead of `VolumeOfSphere`

Comment: `"Please enter the diameter of the circle"` should probably be `"Please enter the diameter of the sphere"`

Comment: Note that 4/3 is approximately 1.33, not 1.1